# sql server using outer join result into table format

Tags: sql-server-2008, html-email, outer-join

I am setting a query to send the results via email and I am getting the result formatting incorrect.

I want to select values from two tables where in table 1 a certain field is null and also add a related field from table 2 where table 1 id = table 2 id. But also include fields in table 1 that may not be in table 2 but has the certain field null.

```
 DECLARE @TITLE NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @BODY NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @TITLE =CAST(( SELECT DISTINCT A.CUSTKEY as 'td','',
 B.CUSTPROJ as 'td','',   A.ITEMS AS 'td','', A.SOLDDATE as 'td','',
 A.LASTORDEREDDATE as 'td','', A.OBJID as 'td'
 FROM PRODUCTDATA AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_TABLE as B
 on A.CUSTkey = B.CUSTkey 
 WHERE LASTORDEREDDATE IS NULL GROUP BY A.CUSTKEY,B.CUSTPROJ, 
 A.ITEMS, A.SOLDDATE, A.OBJID,A.LASTORDEREDDATE
 FOR XML PATH ('tr'), ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

 SET @BODY = '<html><body><H4>NEW CLIENT PURCHASES</H4>
 <table border = 2>
 <tr>
 <th> CUST KEY </th> <th> CLIENT NAME </th> <th> NEW PURCHASES </th>
 <th> SOLD DATE </th> <th> ORDERED DATE </th> <th> PRODUCT ID </th></tr>'

 SET @BODY = @BODY + @TITLE + '</TABLE></BODY></HTML>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='DB Admin',
@body =   @BODY,
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

But it appears as follows:

```
NEW CLIENT PURCHASES
CUSTkEY CLIENT NAME NEW PURCHASES    SOLD DATE      ORDERED DATE PRODUCT ID 
9189ad  PHOEBE       LDS              20130107T12:15:00    NULL         BGD01 
8765ad  MONICA       PANTS            20130107T12:15:00    NULL         BGD01 
3421ad  JOEY         BAG              20130107T12:15:00    NULL         BGD01 
2354ad  RACHEL       HAT              20130107T12:15:00    NULL         BGD01   
7653ef  SHOES     20121213T06:15:00                                     hfd00
```

As you can see the last row happens to be a row in table 1 where the client does not exist in the client table 2 and thus the row should look like this:

```
  CUSTkEY   CLIENT NAME NEW PURCHASES    SOLD DATE       ORDERED DATE    PRODUCT ID 

   7653ef                  SHOES       20121213T06:15:00   NULL             hfd00
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Try to use `XSINIL` in query like `FOR XML PATH ('tr'), ELEMENTS XSINIL`. Maybe it will allow to keep placeholders for empty values

Comment: the xsinil worked...thanks much

Answer (score 1):

To include empty tags when you have several columns with the same name, you have to wrap each column into its own XML generator like this:

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT (SELECT n1) FOR XML PATH('td'),TYPE),
 (SELECT (SELECT n2) FOR XML PATH('td'),TYPE), 
 (SELECT (SELECT n3) FOR XML PATH('td'),TYPE)
FROM (VALUES(NULL,NULL,1))x(n1,n2,n3)
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: I dont understand the from line 'FROM (VALUES(NULL,NULL,1))x(n1,n2,n3)' FROM PRODUCTDATA AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_TABLE as B
 on A.CUSTkey = B.CUSTkey 
 WHERE LASTORDEREDDATE IS NULL GROUP BY A.CUSTKEY,B.CUSTPROJ, 
 A.ITEMS, A.SOLDDATE, A.OBJID,A.LASTORDEREDDATE
 FOR XML PATH ('tr'), ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))